# What is the Android permission needed to save files?

Tags: python, android, kivy, android-permissions, mobile-application

I created an app called [Paint Maker Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pranav.pooruli.pmp) with Kivy and Python code and now it's on the Google Play Store. People have told me the `Save as JPEG` feature doesn't work. And that's true. I want the user to be able to save their work so they can share it with other people. And when a user clicks the `Save as JPEG` button, the drawing gets saved in the current working directory on Linux and Windows. On Android though, the app says the drawing was saved but it never gets saved. Here's the code I used:

```py
# IMPORTS AND A LOT OF OTHER CODE
def save_canvas(self, for_kivy):
    filename = datetime.now().strftime('PMP_Drawing_at_%a_%b_%d_%I:%M:%S:%f_%p_%Y.jpg')
    self.root.export_as_image().save(filename)
    self.btn_col = (uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), 1)
    self.save_btn_jpg.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.clear_btn.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.select_col_btn.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.erase_btn.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_10.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_20.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_30.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_40.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_50.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.pt_60.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.rec_btn.background_color = self.btn_col
    self.cir_btn.background_color = self.btn_col
    popup.pop(filename, Label(text='Drawing saved at:\n' +
                              getcwd() + '.', font_size=self.font_15))
```

I'm pretty sure this is because of some Android permission error. So does anyone know what permission I'm supposed to use? **I've already tried `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.**

Comment: You should include your permission code/file saving code and what versions of Android/devices that code isn't working. Related: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#storage-paths

Comment: It's in the code: `filename = datetime.now().strftime('PMP_Drawing_at_%a_%b_%d_%I:%M:%S:%f_%p_%Y.jpg')
    self.root.export_as_image().save(filename)`.
And it doesn't work on any version of Android.

Comment: Yes, but what is the storage path? Read my link regarding what to do for Android.

Comment: Oh, so do you mean files saved by apps get saved in a specific folder with all app data?

Comment: But if the App Storage Path is not visible to anyone, then how will the user know that the image got saved?

Comment: I get the following error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/android/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .boot import BootImage
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/android/boot.py", line 58
    print "============================================="
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("=============================================")?`. If I use Python 2, I get `ImportError: No module named storage`. What do I do?

Comment: After I fix that, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'android.storage'`.

Comment: I fixed my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my app, but if anyone didn't know how to use special permissions, here's how:

```py
from kivy.utils import platform
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
# Android module doesn't have to be installed because it will automatically get
# included in the APK
# ------ OTHER IMPORTS ------

# ------ APP CODE ------

if __name__ in ['__android__', '__main__']:
 if platform == 'android':
  request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ...]) # All permissions your app requires
 # ------ RUN APP ------
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you accepted the permission by requesting it from an app, not from Manifest?

I hope you can check if the permission in the app information is correct.

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is right

Comment: I don't know much about `AndroidManifest.xml`, Java, Kotlin, and stuff because I'm using Python to develop my app. I also don't know how to ask for the permission or accept the permission. So I don't get a **word** you're saying. ``

Comment: I learned how to request permissions, and now it works! Thanks!